# How to extract row with certain worlds from a result that contains multiple lines

Tags: python, string, python-re

Trying to find row with `Device is ready` string from `response_without_empty_lines` that contains multiple lines:

```
lines = decoded_bytes.split("\n")
    non_empty_lines = [line for line in lines if line.strip() != ""]
    response_without_empty_lines = ""
    for line in non_empty_lines:
        response_without_empty_lines += line + "\n"
```

here i got only lines that contain data, next I want to find a line containing `Device is ready`:

```
for i in response_without_empty_lines:
    if 'Device is ready' in i:
        print(i)
```

... and get nothing. where am i wrong?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what `lines` looks like that way everyone will have a better idea of what's occurring in your code.

Comment: ```in``` is used for searching an element in a list, you can use ```find``` for strings, also don't iterate through response_without_empty_lines because it is a string so ```i``` will be a character at a time, do ```for i in non_empty_lines```

Comment: [10] - Device is loading...
[13] - Software version 0.0.2
[3016] - Device is ready...

Answer (score 0):

you can use
 `i.find("Device is ready") > 0`,
`find` returns a positive number(the index of the first encounter of the parameter) if found, or -1 otherwise

Comment: what would the syntax look like in this case?

for i in response_without_empty_lines:
    i.find("Device is ready") > 0
    print(i)

Comment: ```for i in non_empty_lines: i.find("Device is ready") > 0 print(i)```  ,   the way you've done it makes the i take every character not every line

Comment: in this case returns each character on a separate line

Answer (score 0):

Just make the `response_without_empty_lines = []`
then in the for loop:

```
response_without_empty_lines.append(line)
```

Comment: like this:
response_without_empty_lines = []
    for i in response_without_empty_lines:
        if 'Device is ready' in i:
            response_without_empty_lines.append(line)
            print(i)

Answer (score 0):

```
decoded_bytes = "Device is ready haha\nAnother phrase"

lines = decoded_bytes.split("\n")
non_empty_lines = [line for line in lines if line.strip() != ""]
response_without_empty_lines = ""

for line in non_empty_lines:
    response_without_empty_lines += line + "\n"

for i in non_empty_lines:
    if i.find("Device is ready") >= 0:
        print(i)
```

my bad, it was =>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking if the line is not empty, you can check if the line contains `Device is ready`.

Then the for comprehension will give a list of lines that contain that sub string.

```
decoded_bytes = ("This is a test\n\n"
                            "Where the Device is ready\n"
                            "test 1\n"
                            "test 2\n"
                            "Device is ready")
non_empty_lines = [line for line in decoded_bytes.split("\n") if "Device is ready" in line]
print(non_empty_lines)
```

Output

```
['Where the Device is ready', 'Device is ready']
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/76dnnA)

Comment: Thanks, i'll check later!